# How to combine all the words of a sentence extracted with a regex?

Tags: regex, linux, awk

I would like to combine with a linux command, if possible, all the words that start with a capital letter, excluding the one at the beginning of the line. The goal is to create edges between these words.
For example:

```
My friend John met Beatrice and Lucio.
```

The result I would like to have should be:

- John, Beatrice
- John, Lucio
- Beatrice, Lucio

I managed to get all the words that start with a capital letter, excluding the word at the beginning of the line through a regex. The regex is:

```
*cat gov.json | grep -oP "\b([A-Z][a-z']*)(\s[A-Z][a-z']*)*\b | ^(\s*.*?\s).*" > nodes.csv*
```

The nodes managed to enter them individually in column, ie:

- John
- Beatrice
- Lucio

The goal now is to create the possible combinations between names that start with a capital letter and put them into a file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another `awk` script doing the task, building the output while reading input.

`script.awk` allowing duplicate names.

```
BEGIN {FPAT =  " [[:upper:]][[:alpha:]]+"}
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) {
        for (name in namesArr) {
            namePairsArr[pairsCount++] = namesArr[name] $i;
        }
        namesArr[namesCount++] = $i;
    }   
}
END {for (i = 0; i < pairsCount; i++) print namePairsArr[i];}
```

If duplicate names not allowed, `script.awk` is:

```
BEGIN {FPAT =  " [[:upper:]][[:alpha:]]+"}
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) {
        if (nameSeenArr[$i]) continue;
        nameSeenArr[$i] = 1;
        for (name in namesArr) {
              namePairsArr[pairsCount++] = namesArr[name] $i;
        }
        namesArr[namesCount++] = $i;
    }
}
END {for (i = 0; i < pairsCount; i++) print namePairsArr[i];}**
```

run

```
awk -f script.awk gov.json > nodes.csv
```

sample input file:

```
My friend John met Beatrice and Lucio
My friend Johna met Beatricea and Lucioa
```

sample output:

```
 John Beatrice
 John Lucio
 Beatrice Lucio
 John Johna
 Beatrice Johna
 Lucio Johna
 John Beatricea
 Beatrice Beatricea
 Lucio Beatricea
 Johna Beatricea
 John Lucioa
 Beatrice Lucioa
 Lucio Lucioa
 Johna Lucioa
 Beatricea Lucioa
```

Comment: Nice Answer. If instead the phrase is "My friend John Reds met Beatrice " how would you chain "John Reds, Beatrice" (always basing on capitalized names)?

Comment: thanks @Emanuele Bosimini, please mark as answer. All capital words are captured, no matter the order. RegExp pattern for `FPAT` identifies all Capitalized words. A word consist of alpha chars only. No symbols (`-~'"^)`)or digits.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for FPAT. awk strings, fields, and arrays start at 1, not zero, so don't start arrays you write your self at zero or it'll lead to confusion/bugs later. `if (nameSeenArr[$i]) continue;
        nameSeenArr[$i] = 1;` is more commonly/idiomatically written as just `if (!nameSeenArr[$i]++) {`

Comment: What if we had a JSON file that is an array of objects like this: ``` lang-js [{"title1":"David and Mary","abstract1":"Lucy"},{"title2":"Andrew","abstract2":"Lawrence"}] ``` and wanted to obtain combinations of proper names happening to be at the same time inside the same object: like (David, Mary)(David, Lucy)(Mary,Lucy) (Andrew,Lawrence), how the code here above would change ? P.S. In particular how would it be if we did not want to get couples like (Andrew,Lucy) - because they hasn't appeared in the same object?

Comment: I would used the same logic but different pattern matching. Or even consider `jc` command to process JSON data. You can ask a question as well.

Comment: Could I create a "for loop" with NR in which the NF loop is nested to solve it?

Comment: In response to @eddybudge. When comes to extracting data from input line `$0` , better use `split` command or `patsplit` command, into array. No need for loops.

Answer (score 5):

If order of the pairs in the output doesn't matter:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[^[:alpha:]]+"; OFS=", " }
{
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ /^[[:upper:]]/) {
            words[$i]
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (word1 in words) {
        for (word2 in words) {
            if (word1 != word2) {
                print word1, word2
            }
        }
        delete words[word1]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Beatrice, Lucio
Beatrice, John
Lucio, John
```

If the order does matter then:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[^[:alpha:]]"; OFS=", " }
{
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ /^[[:upper:]]/) {
            if ( !seen[$i]++ ) {
                words[++numWords] = $i
            }
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (word1nr=1; word1nr<=numWords; word1nr++) {
        word1 = words[word1nr]
        for (word2nr=word1nr+1; word2nr<=numWords; word2nr++) {
            word2 = words[word2nr]
            print word1, word2
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
John, Beatrice
John, Lucio
Beatrice, Lucio
```

In the above, `file` contains the original input, e.g. `My friend John met Beatrice and Lucio.`

Comment: You should be asking "what if..." and other questions of the person whose answer you accepted.

Comment: What if we had a JSON file that is an array of objects like this: ``` lang-js [{"title1":"David and Mary","abstract1":"Lucy"},{"title2":"Andrew","abstract2":"Lawrence"}] ``` and wanted to obtain combinations of proper names happening to be at the same time inside the same object: like (David, Mary)(David, Lucy)(Mary,Lucy) (Andrew,Lawrence), how the code here above would change ? P.S. In particular how would it be if we did not want to get couples like (Andrew,Lucy) - because they hasn't appeared in the same object?

Comment: Would an NR for loop be enough if we nested inside it the NF loop you showed in this example ?

Comment: Again - You should be directing followup questions to the person whose answer you accepted. Or just ask a whole new question with it's own concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

When you have the results in an array, you can loop with

```
names=( John Beatrice Lucio )
max=${#names[@]}

for ((i1=0; i1<max; i1++)); do
  for ((i2=i1+1; i2<max; i2++)); do
    echo "${names[$i1]}, ${names[$i2]}"
  done
done
```

When you don't have to much names (length arglist) you can use

```
set -- John Beatrice Lucio
for a; do
    shift
    for b; do
        printf "%s, %s\n" "$a" "$b"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If the only problem would be the first word of our string, we would simply add a `.` in our expression:

```
.([A-Z][a-z']+)
```

or we would be adding an space as a left boundary:

```
(\s+)([A-Z][a-z']+)(\s+)?
```

Our desired word is in this capturing group:

```
([A-Z][a-z']+)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CSpIST/1/)

yet this would fail if we'd have such cases as:

```
My friend Alice O'Neal met Beatrice and Lucio
```

for which we can expand our desired output group.

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired and you wish to modify it, please visit this link at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/CSpIST/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the possible pairs of names, let's say you have created *names.txt* containing:

```
    John
    Beatrice
    Lucio
```

I'd try this in bash:

```
  $ for n in `cat names.txt`
  > do for m in `cat names.txt`
  >   do if [ $m != $n ]; then
  >        echo $n, $m
  >      fi
  >   done
  > done
  John, Beatrice
  John, Lucio
  Beatrice, John
  Beatrice, Lucio
  Lucio, John
  Lucio, Beatrice
```

Comment: http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_06_03, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: Whaddya know, I'm old school